# How to add a Chatter in existing odoo module

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to add a chatter in **fleet** *in Vehicles Services Logs*
and it give me this error when I am trying to update the inherit module that responsible to add the chatter,

this is the model:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Fleet_Chatter_service(models.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.chatter.service'
    _inherit = ['fleet.vehicle.log.services', 'mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    _description = "fleet chatter in cost and service"
```

this is the view:

```
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="odt_fleet_service_chatter_form">
      <field name="name">odt.fleet.chatter.service</field>
      <field name="model">fleet.chatter.service</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_log_services_view_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//form/sheet" position="after">
              <div class="oe_chatter">
                  <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                  <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
                  <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread" />
              </div>
          </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

and this is the error:

Error:

> Odoo Server Error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 394, in *check_xml
> self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 961, in postprocess_and_fields
> self.raise_view_error(*('Model not found: %(model)s') % dict(model=model), view_id)   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 614, in raise_view_error
> raise ValueError(message) ValueError: Model not found: fleet.chatter.service
>
> Error context: View `odt.fleet.chatter.service` [view_id: 2990,
> xml_id: n/a, model: fleet.chatter.service, parent_id: 494]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
> self._tag_root(de)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in
> _tag_root
> f(rec)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
> record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 4168, in
> _load_records
> records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line
> 4082, in _load_records_create
> return self.create(values)   File "", line 2, in create   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 336, in
> _model_create_multi
> return create(self, arg)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 475, in create
> return super(View, self).create(vals_list)   File "", line 2, in create   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 336, in
> _model_create_multi
> return create(self, arg)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 3843, in create
> fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\fields.py", line 1155, in
> determine_inverse
> getattr(records, self.inverse)()   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 299, in _inverse_arch
> view.write(data)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 493, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 3632, in write
> real_recs._validate_fields(vals, inverse_fields)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 1206, in
> _validate_fields
> check(self)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 396, in *check_xml
> raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (*("Error while validating view"), tools.ustr(e))) odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error while
> validating view\n\nModel not found: fleet.chatter.service\n\nError
> context:\nView `odt.fleet.chatter.service`\n[view_id: 2990, xml_id:
> n/a, model: fleet.chatter.service, parent_id: 494]', None)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 624, in
> _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 310, in
> _handle_exception
> raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in
> reraise
> raise value   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
> result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
> return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
> return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
> result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 915, in **call**
> return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
> response = f(*args, **kw)   File "c:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1343,
> in call_button
> action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)   File "c:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1331,
> in _call_kw
> return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
> result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
> result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line
> 72, in check_and_log
> return method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line
> 634, in button_immediate_upgrade
> return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py",
> line 573, in _button_immediate_function
> modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in
> new
> odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 419, in
> load_modules
> force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 315, in
> load_marked_modules
> perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 225, in
> load_module_graph
> load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in
> load_data
> tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 736, in
> convert_file
> convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 803, in
> convert_xml_import
> obj.parse(doc.getroot())   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 721, in parse
> exc_info[2]   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 13, in
> reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
> self._tag_root(de)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in
> _tag_root
> f(rec)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
> record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 4168, in
> _load_records
> records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line
> 4082, in _load_records_create
> return self.create(values)   File "", line 2, in create   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 336, in
> _model_create_multi
> return create(self, arg)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 475, in create
> return super(View, self).create(vals_list)   File "", line 2, in create   File
> "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\api.py", line 336, in
> _model_create_multi
> return create(self, arg)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 3843, in create
> fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\fields.py", line 1155, in
> determine_inverse
> getattr(records, self.inverse)()   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 299, in _inverse_arch
> view.write(data)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 493, in write
> res = super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 3632, in write
> real_recs._validate_fields(vals, inverse_fields)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\models.py", line 1206, in
> _validate_fields
> check(self)   File "C:\odt_work\zawaj\odoo-13\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py",
> line 396, in *check_xml
> raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (*("Error while validating view"), tools.ustr(e))) odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while
> validating view
>
> Model not found: fleet.chatter.service

```
Error context:
View `odt.fleet.chatter.service`
[view_id: 2990, xml_id: n/a, model: fleet.chatter.service, parent_id: 494]
None" while parsing file:/c:/odt_work/zawaj/zawaj_custom/odt_fleet_chatter/views/chatter_service_view.xml:1, near
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="odt_fleet_service_chatter_form">
      <field name="name">odt.fleet.chatter.service</field>
      <field name="model">fleet.chatter.service</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="50"/>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="fleet.fleet_vehicle_log_services_view_form"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//form/sheet" position="after">
              <div class="oe_chatter">
                  <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers"/>
                  <field name="activity_ids" widget="mail_activity"/>
                  <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
              </div>
          </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Same problem i'm having

Answer (score 0):

Try to inherit "mail.activity.mixin" as well since it is the one that adds the "activity_ids" field which you use in your view.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api

class Fleet_Chatter_service(models.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.chatter.service'
    _inherit = [
        'fleet.vehicle.log.services', 'mail.thread',
        'mail.activity.mixin', 'ir.needaction_mixin'
    ]
    _description = "fleet chatter in cost and service"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit "mail.thread" in your class:

```
class Fleet_Chatter_service(models.Model):
    _name = 'fleet.chatter.service'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'another.module.needed']
```

Now you have to add the chatter inside your view:
In case of custom view, put it just after the :

```
        <div class="oe_chatter">
                <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
        </div>
```

Same if you are working on an inherited view, use this Xpath :

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet" position="after">
    <div class="oe_chatter">
          <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
    </div>
</xpath>
```

Regards,